# Mock a singleton class In Ruby on Rails using Rspec

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec

I try to create a mock for follow class:

```
module EstablishmentsQueryService
  class << self
    def find_by_id(id)
      Establishment.find_by!(id:)
    rescue ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound
      raise EstablishmentNotFoundError.new id
    end
  end
end
```

to try test my controller

```
# frozen_string_literal: true

module Api
  module V1
    # Controllewr to manager Establishments
    class EstablishmentsController < Api::V1::ApiController
      before_action :validate_id, only: %i[destroy update show]
      before_action :load_establishment, only: %i[destroy update show]

      def show; end

      def create
        @establishment = Establishment.new(establishment_params)
        @establishment = EstablishmentService.save(@establishment)
        render status: :created
      end

      def destroy
        EstablishmentService.delete(@establishment)
      end

      def update
        @establishment.attributes = establishment_params
        @establishment = EstablishmentService.save(@establishment)
      end

      private

      def validate_id
        message = I18n.t('establishment_controller.id.invalid', id: params[:id])
        UuidValidateService.call(params[:id], message)
      end

      def load_establishment
        @establishment = EstablishmentsQueryService.find_by_id(params[:id])
      end

      def establishment_params
        params.require(:establishment).permit(:name, :cnpj, :description)
      end
    end
  end
end
```

follow my test:

```
# frozen_string_literal: true

require 'rails_helper'

RSpec.describe 'Api::V1::Establishments', type: :request do
  describe 'GET /api/v1/establishments/:id' do
    context 'when has establishment' do
      let(:establishment) { build(:establishment, id: p, created_at: DateTime.now, updated_at: DateTime.now) }

      before do
        allow_any_instance_of(EstablishmentsQueryService).to receive(:find_by_id).and_return(establishment)
        get "/api/v1/establishments/#{establishment.id}"
      end

      it 'then http status is ok' do
        expect_status_is_ok
      end

      it 'has body equal to expected' do
        except_field_by_field(establishment, body_to_open_struct, %i[id name cnpj description])
      end
    end

    context 'when has no establishment' do
      before do
        get "/api/v1/establishments/#{UUID.new.generate}"
      end

      it 'then http status is not_found' do
        expect_status_is_not_found
      end
    end

    context 'when use invalid id' do
      before { get "/api/v1/establishments/#{FFaker::Lorem.word}" }

      it 'then http status is bad_request' do
        expect_status_is_bad_request
      end
    end

  end

  describe 'PUT /api/v1/establishments/:id' do
    let(:establishments_query_service) { allow(EstablishmentsQueryService) }
    let(:establishments_service) { allow(EstablishmentsService) }

    context 'when updated with success' do
      let(:establishment) { build(:establishment) }
      let(:id) { UUID.new.generate }

      before do
        establishments_query_service.to receive(:find_by_id) { |p| build(:establishment, id: p, created_at: DateTime.now, updated_at: DateTime.now) }
        establishments_service.to receive(:save) do |p|
          to_return = p
          to_return.created_at = DateTime.now
          to_return.updated_at = DateTime.now
        end
        put "/api/v1/establishments/#{id}"
      end

      it 'then http status is ok' do
        expect_status_is_ok
      end

      it 'has body equal to expected' do
        actual = body_to_open_struct
        except_field_by_field(establishment, actual, %i[name cnpj description])
        expected(actual.id).to eq(id)
      end
    end

    context 'when has no establishment' do
      
    end

    context 'when has constraint violation' do
      
    end
  end

  describe 'DELETE /api/v1/establishments/:id' do

  end

  describe 'POST /api/v1/establishments' do

  end
end
```

If I work using allow_any_instance_of a test ignore configuration, use a real configuration and fails because has no data stores. If I use double I received a follow error:

Api::V1::Establishments GET /api/v1/establishments/:id when has establishment then http status is ok
Failure/Error: allow_any_instance_of(EstablishmentsQueryService).to receive(:find_by_id).and_return(establishment)
EstablishmentsQueryService does not implement #find_by_id

I think the right away is user allow_any_instance_of because this config is for static methods, but didn't work

how can I mock my class to test my controller? I using Ruby 3.1.2, rails 7.0.3 and rspec-rails 5.1.2
thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found my problem, I forgot to definie expected params in my confi using with()

allow(EstablishmentsQueryService).to receive(:find_by_id)**.with(establishment.id)**.and_return(establishment)

Comment: The `with` was not the issue. The issue was that `find_by_id` is not an instance method which is why the error stated "EstablishmentsQueryService does not implement #find_by_id". The pound notation `#find_by_id` indicates instance method. In this answer you corrected this by changing `allow_any_instance_of` to `allow` which is now stubbing `EstablishmentsQueryService::find_by_id` (class instance method) rather than `EstablishmentsQueryService#find_by_id` (instance method). If you were to remove the `with` but leave everything else here as is it would still function accordingly.

Comment: @engineersmnky I understood what you said and I will fix my question to explain better and right, thank you and sorry

Comment: @engineersmnky I review my cod, redo my tests with wrong config and fix my question, thank you :)